# open fragment from Firebase onMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to open a fragment when a new Notification is received. For this I use a BroadcastReceiver. Problem is I'm not getting the message in my Activity from `sendNotification` method inside `FirebaseMessagingService` class. I think the issue is I declared the IntentFilter inside `onCreate` and its not being called when I click on the push notification. Is there any other way to do this?

```css
// Globally declared
 private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
 
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
  
  // Open a fragment automatically
   if (findViewById(R.id.frame) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            myFragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            myFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new ProdList()).commit();
        }
        

        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction("com.sam.CUSTOM_INTENT");


    } 
 
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
 
 private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals("com.sam.CUSTOM_INTENT")) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GOT MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                InventoryList il = new InventoryList();
                replaceFragment(il,"IL");
            }
        }
    };
```

```html
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {        

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
                
                String value = entry.getValue();
               
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(value);
                    
                    sendNotification(obj.getString("message"),"SUCCESS");
                    

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }


    }
 
 
 private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String param) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  intent.setAction("MESSAGE");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_com.sam.CUSTOM_INTENTr)
                .setContentTitle("Nika")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Why did you use broadcast receiver inside home activity itself? You are already coming on HomeActivity when notification will be clicked right?

Comment: Cuz I need to open fragment using FrameLayout which is in HomeActivity's layout.

Comment: but you are already replacing on oncreate method then what's the need of broadcast receiver?

Comment: Yes, but when I get the broadcast, I want to replace whatever fragment is currently opened with my desired fragment.

Comment: Even if I delete the code to automatically replace fragment in onCreate, it still is not reaching to the `onReceive` method of `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want BroadcastReceiver to get the broadcast, you have to actually send the Broadcast. Put this code in your `onMessageReceived()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sam.CUSTOM_INTENT");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This snippet will send the broadcast to all registered BroadcastReceivers with IntentFilter matching action `"com.sam.CUSTOM_INTENT"`.

So, with current implementation, your activity will get broadcast when it is resumed.

Comment: Its still not reaching the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver @Wojciech

Comment: Are you sure it's reaching onMessageReceived method of the FcmListenerService?

Is activity is foreground when you're testing?

Comment: Yes, HomeActivity is opening when I click on the notification. But not reaching BroadcastReceiver. @Wojciech

Comment: BroadcastReceiver will be triggered only when it is registered, so when the activity is resumed. 

To solve your problem you should probably use onNewIntent() method of activity
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)
instead of BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I checked.  `onNewIntent()` is not called when I click on the push notification. Only `onResume()` is called. @Wojciech