# How to open a Fragment after notification click? Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a a function "send_notification" with firebase function and node.js and now at the end it's difficult to figure out how to open a Fragment instead of an Activity in my FirebaseMessagingService class.

this is my code

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);



        String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo_login)
                        .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                        .setContentText(notification_message);




        //i need to open a fragment not Main Activiti
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        //----------------------------------------------------










        int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());



    }


}
```

Comment: is your fragment in your mainActivity or not

Comment: Lorenzo you must to open an Activity that hold your Fragment.

Comment: Yes my all my fragment are inside MainActivity

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44011011/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/42832534/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/40211624/1531971 and too many others to count. Explain how those do or do not apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to start commit Fragment in FirebaseMessagingService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832534/how-to-start-commit-fragment-in-firebasemessagingservice)